# Add new word to Slack's spell checker

Tags: slack, spell-checking

When you you type a word in Slack and it is wrongly spelled it is highlighted.
I want to add a word which is highlighted in Slack as wrong (Salesforce it is) and make Slack understand that the word is spelled correctly. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: SO is only about programming related topics. I would suggest to place your question on this partner forum instead: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/
And you also want to include which client you are using, because e.g. the spelling check on web clients are not done by Slack

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129798/add-new-word-to-slacks-spell-checker